# DSolve output - understanding how to extract result

Tags: differential-equations

I'm a little confused with how to use the output from `DSolve`. The following works

```
s = DSolve[{y'[x] == x, y[0] == 0}, y[x], x];
Plot[y[x] /. s, {x, 1, 10}]
```

but I don't understand how it works. I am familiar with `/. a -> b` which will replace a with b, but I don't get what `y[x] /. s` is doing?

Answer (score 2):

`Dsolve[]`, like `Solve[]` (but unlike `Resolve[]`) returns replacement rules. You are replacing the value of `y[]`returned by your solve command

Comment: Thanks. I see whats going on. I can declare a mapping such as map = {a->b}; then i can use this mapping variable in a any ReplaceAll command i.e a /. map or {a,a} /. map.

Comment: @David Yes. Replacement rules (term rewriting) are very important in Mathematica.